# How can I connect to the Azure AD B2C from Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Azure AD B2C Tenant and a few users in it.

1. How can I use the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to update those users properties (default as well as custom)?
2. What endpoint I need to use and what credentials to be used to login to the Microsoft Graph Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [you must use Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) and [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C tenant, since Microsoft Graph doesn't support some of the user properties that are used by Azure AD B2C.

You can sign in as either a [Company/Global Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#company-administrator) or [User Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#user-administrator) user to Azure AD Graph Explorer.

Comment: Azure AD Graph Explorer is broken. Here is the GitHub [ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26147). I get the same error when I try to login with the administrator account. I have access to the Azure Portal as well as create users with this account.

Comment: Are you logging in to Graph Explorer with a Microsoft Account or a work account? You must use a work account.

Comment: I tried the account that I use to login to the Azure account. I use that account to create CosmosDB and even used that to create the Azure AD B2C. I see the sources as *Microsoft Account* for that account. Can I convert the account that I use to login to the Azure to be a *work account*?

Comment: No, you can't convert an existing account from a Microsoft Account to a work account, so you'll have to create a new account as a work account and then log in to Graph Explorer with this new account.

Comment: Is this still true? The first link now takes you to a page which says to use Microsoft Graph.

Comment: It isn't true anymore. Azure AD Graph was discontinued.